# How many former Russian players have moved from RUS or FID registration to another country since the May 2023 offer?

Tags: fide

> "most are likely to do so Do you have any sources for this? "

The quote comes from a comment made by Allure to [this post of mine](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/41718/does-the-russian-chess-federation-switching-to-the-acf-actually-make-it-harder-f/41721#41721) where I claimed:

> FIDE have made it possible for Russian players to move cost-free and without delays to the European federation of their choice and most are likely to do so.

Of course I didn't have inside information but now that the 31st August deadline has passed we can see how many have already taken advantage of the offer and changed federation for free.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the data in the [FIDE rating database](https://ratings.fide.com/download.phtml) here is a list of the 21 Russian players rated above 2600 who were registered as RUS in February 2022 (when the conflict started) and who changed their federation from RUS by 31st August 2023.

**FullName  FIDEID  Code    Rating**
Vitiugov, Nikita    4152956 **ENG** 2726
Andreikin, Dmitry   4158814 FID 2724
Esipenko, Andrey    24175439    FID 2714
Fedoseev, Vladimir  24130737    **SLO** 2704
Alekseenko, Kirill  4135539 **AUT** 2702
Sarana, Alexey  24133795    **SRB** 2685
Svidler, Peter  4102142 FID 2683
Predke, Alexandr    24107581    **SRB** 2682
Oparin, Grigoriy    24125890    **USA** 2681
Sjugirov, Sanan 4189302 **HUN** 2680
Najer, Evgeniy  4118987 FID 2661
Inarkiev, Ernesto   4162722 FID 2659
Demchenko, Anton    4160258 **SLO** 2654
Malakhov, Vladimir  4120787 FID 2652
Rakhmanov, Aleksandr    4173708 FID 2640
Motylev, Alexander  4121830 **ROU** 2633
Chigaev, Maksim 4108116 **ESP** 2631
Paravyan, David 4194985 FID 2617
Antipov, Mikhail Al.    4107012 FID 2615
Goryachkina, Aleksandra 4147103 FID 2610
Lysyj, Igor 4150120 FID 2603

7 out of the top 10 took advantage of FIDE's offer and changed to another country federation. 10 out of the top 21 did so.

Comment: Its sad they label Russian players for reasons outside of chess.

Comment: This does not look correct, it's missing e.g. Grischuk, Nepo, Karjakin who are all >2600 rating too.

Comment: @Allure: It's a list only of the people *who changed federations*, Grischuk, Nepo, and Karjakin are all still registered with Russia.

Comment: @NoahSnyder some players list FID. That's RUS also right?

Comment: No, FID is Fide not Russia.